# Como rodar aplicações em background usando Docker?

Tags: docker

Estou tentando rodar minha aplicação em Python dentro de um container, só que preciso instalar uma dependência do proxy que utilizo: Luminati, o problema é que aparentemente o luminati não está rodando em background após eu inicializar o container.

Eu tentei rodar da seguinte maneira:

```
docker run -it test_app:latest
```

Ao rodar um `ps ax` a aplicação do luminati não está rodando!

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/shared
    networks:
      - vnet-front

networks:
   vnet-front:
     driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine AS build-ev

RUN apk add nodejs
RUN apk add npm
RUN npm install -g @luminati-io/luminati-proxy --unsafe-perm
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN luminati --config luminati.json
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "test.py"]
```

Comment: Quero que o container rode o comando `luminati --config luminati.json` e também o meu entrypoint, o problema é que quando eu rodo em modo interativo os processos não estão rodando.

Comment: Vou testar só um momento.

Comment: Deu na mesma, quando dou um ps ax: `bash-4.4# ps ax
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/bash
    8 root      0:00 ps ax`

Comment: Ok, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que possa iniciar sua aplicação no momento em que o container é chamado, ao invés de usar o `RUN` você usa o `CMD`:

***Dockerfile alterado:***

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine AS build-ev

RUN apk add nodejs
RUN apk add npm
RUN npm install -g @luminati-io/luminati-proxy --unsafe-perm
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

CMD luminati --config luminati.json && python test.py
```

Assim, no momento em que *startar* sua imagem (algo como):

```
docker run -d -p 22999:80 test_app:latest
```

A aplicação (*luminati*) vai estar sendo executada E o seu `test.py` também.

Comment: Vou testar e lhe aviso! Obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, você sabe me dizer o porque antes não funcionava? É necessário mapear a porta? Consegui rodar aqui sem precisar mapear.

Comment: Acredito que era porque estava usando o `RUN` para iniciar o *luminati*, ele é usado durante o processo de *build* da imagem, e não como você tava fazendo, chamando sua aplicação. Dá uma olhada na [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run), explica bem isso.

Comment: Ah, my bad! Obrigado amigo.